# Is it possible to forward template arguments to make_* without deduction?

Tags: c++, templates

As the title says, I would like to do exactly that.
I have a minimal class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    /// I only need the type T, but no T instance
    /// needed.
    template <typename T>
    Foo(const std::string&);

    Foo(int);

private:
    ...
};
```

And I need to create a shared pointer from this class. The trivial
approach tells us to do this (for example, for T=int):

> std::shared_pointer foo_int = std::shared_pointer??("");

or directly:

```
auto foo_int = std::shared_pointer<Foo>??("");
```

But, following best practices, one should use make_shared (or make_unique
if it were a `std::unique_pointer`):

```
auto foo_int = std::make_shared<Foo>("");
```

So, it is possible to do it?

Comment: `new std::shared_ptr<Foo>` doesn't make much sense anyway: you're allocating a raw pointer to a smart pointer. Rarely use the `new` keyword at all.

Comment: @aschepler ops! Thanks, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

```
/// I only need the type T, but no T instance
/// needed.
template <typename T>
Foo(const std::string&);
```

There is no way to explicitly specify template arguments for a constructor. They can only be determined by deduction or from default template arguments. So this constructor can never actually be used.

One possible workaround would be to use a tag parameter and argument instead:

```
template <typename> struct type_tag {};

class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Foo(type_tag<T>, const std::string&);
    // ...
};
```

Then you can do things like:

```
auto foo_int = std::make_shared<Foo>(type_tag<int>{}, "");
```

Comment: What do you think it will be better? That o passing a dummy T?

Comment: You mean like having an actual `T` parameter in `Foo(T, const std::string&)`? That's certainly simpler, but could cause issues if `T` is a class with no default constructor, or no accessible constructor, or all constructors have unwanted side effects or expensive computations.

Comment: then perhaps an unused const T& ?